# Transfer data to TinyMCE .NET MVC layout

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, tinymce

We are using Tiny MCE editor on our .NET MVC app. All was done by this example: http://tugberkugurlu.com/archive/tinymce-html-text-editior-and-asp-net-mvc-setting-it-up-has-become-easy-with-nuget

We have a custom drop-down list in template for MCE. We need to transfer data to this dd list.

Any ideas how to do this? Just remember, that TinyMCE is another layout, done from the example and generated while we install MCE from Nuget.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ViewBag provide the possibility to do this. Data from ViewBag will be available in this case.